# Can I Reuse a Value in an Update Statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to update two fields in a table but the second one depends on the new value of the first. Also the calculation of the first is an intensive one, so I don't want to execute it twice. To make myself clearer here is an example which works but executes the calculation twice:

```
update MyTable
set col1 = dbo.HeavyCalculationFunction(),
    col2 = dbo.HeavyCalculationFunction() + 1
```

What I would like to do is:

```
update MyTable
set col1 = dbo.HeavyCalculationFunction(),
    col2 = col1 + 1
```

This also executs successfully but uses the old value of col1 when calculating thew new col2 value. So is it possible to use the new one, i.e.:

```
update MyTable
set col1 = dbo.HeavyCalculationFunction(),
    col2 = col1(NEW VALUE) + 1
```

Comment: could you not wrap this in a transaction and just do two update statements if you don't want to calculate that field twice?

Comment: how about storing function result to variable

Comment: Before the execution of the total update command only it will store the new value in col1. You can use two update statements

Comment: @RichBenner I could do that but it's a second update. Having about 2 million records, I am looking for a solution which will not require a second update

Comment: @MyoMyintAung Good idea and it works (see answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest to use variable to store function result.

```
Declare @tempData [some data type]
SET @tempData = dbo.HeavyCalculationFunction();

update MyTable
set col1 = @tempData,
    col2 = @tempData + 1
```

Comment: That won't work for multiple records (because HeavyCalculationFunction actually uses another field from the record which I didn't mention) but the idea led me to the solution above which works

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the idea to @MyoMyintAung:

```
declare @c1 int
update MyTable
set @c1 = col1 = dbo.HeavyCalculationFunction(),
    col2 = @c1 + 1
```

Comment: MyoMyintAung was faster than you, see comment above. But thank you as well, I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: Actually I was faster @vladimir

Answer (score 2):

Try using a variable :

```
DECLARE @Varname <TheType>
SELECT @Varname = dbo.HeavyCalculationFunction()
update MyTable
    set col1 = @Varname,
        col2 = @Varname + 1
```

Or two update statements :

```
update MyTable
    set col1 = dbo.HeavyCalculationFunction(),

update MyTable
    set col2 = col1 + 1
```